# Gluon Project - Springboot Dependencies not found when i run /.gradle run

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, javafx, gluon

Here is my issue :

When i run my mainClass as java application everything goes good : [image]
but when i run ./gradle run springboot dependencies not found in the classPath : [image: Image2]

the build.gradle :  [GitHub Repository link to file](https://github.com/raidentel/reactive-client/blob/master/build.gradle)

Can anyone try to fix with me the issue i ll be more than glad !!!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by adding this in the build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.30'
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'application'
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign:1.4.7.RELEASE"
}
```

And now when i run /.gradle run -> it shows [image]